# Registration Password

Tags: passwords, appsec, email

Is it best to create an application that allows a user to sign up with username and email at the beginning and password once you click the generated email sent to you or should the password entering be in place before you get an email to continue sign up process?

Comment: Using a generated email is typically done to curtail bot signups and that the email address is legitimate.

Comment: shouldn't you set the password in signup before clicking the generated email ?

Comment: Communication with the user is important and therefore IMO, if you want to set the password via signup you need to use a "complete registration" link (with expiration) in an email to ensure the email address is legit.  If the email works, it doesn't matter when they generate the password as they can always use their email address to reset their password.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two, the prior method is more secure and should be used. As imjoevasquez said, its used to curtail signups and make sure email address is legitimate.
The other thing you could do is send a randomly generated code to the email, and ask to enter that to let the user create the account.

Answer (score 0):

It is a security vs convenience tradeoff. In the first method, it takes longer for the user to register and get access to the service but the server is able to verify the user's email address. Vice versa in the second method. So it is up to the application developer what he/she wants to prioritise.